# Prestashop : Invalid security key (AND, can I delete _RIJNDAEL_KEY_ ?)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, rijndael

I'm migrating a 2008 old prestashop install (which has been upgraded to 1.6) towards an all new clean prestashop install on a new server.

The possibilities of import/export didn't seem to work so well, I especially didn't know how to transfer users and their crypted passwords (missing in the export file). So I eventually decided to use the same database used in the original website to absolutely preserve everything perfectly.

From there, two questions (I'm open to any recommandations of course) :

- I replaced the COOKIE_KEY for the former key in the configuration file, so that the passwords keep working. But when I do that, and try to go to a new page in the Back-Office, I have an error message saying **"Invalid security Key"**
  How can I fix that ?
- My second point is potentially linked :
  The config file of my former website didn't contain a _RIJNDAEL_KEY_ and _RIJNDAEL_IV_ key even though it had been upgraded to Prestashop 1.6.
  So I totally **deleted these two lines** from the config file of my new clean install, and don't have the "Invalid security key" error message aforementioned anymore.
  How can I fix this in a cleaner way ?
  Is it a problem to not have the _RIJNDAEL_KEY_ and _RIJNDAEL_IV_ in my config file, can I do without them ? (everything seems to work)

Hoping it's clear enough, I stay at disposal !
Thanks in advance for your help !